# GroovyEvaluator not found

Tags: java, struts2, jasper-reports, ireport, eclipse-juno

I'll try to do my PIE 3D  report in *iReport*, in my struts.xml i got this to call my report.

```xml
<action name="cargaReporte" 
        class="com.techera.eventos.action.MisVisitasAction" 
        method="cargaReporte">              
    <result name="success" type="jasper">
        <param name="location">/WEB-INF/jsp/reportes/reporteMisVisitas.jasper</param>
        <param name="dataSource">visitas</param>
        <param name="format">PDF</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

in my jsp i got this

```
<a href="cargaReporte">Reporte</a>
```

and when i clicked the link, the error is this

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.GroovyEvaluator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        ...
```

Someone to tellme what I can do wrong?

I use the libraries:

groovy-all-1.7.5.jar

- iText-2.1.7.jar
- jasperreports-4.5.0.jar
- jcommon-1.0.15.jar
- jfreechart-1.0.12.jar
- struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.3.1.1.jar
- struts2-jquery-chart-plugin-3.3.1.jar

Comment: There is no ***net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.GroovyEvaluator*** class in *JasperReports 4.5.0*. You can try to use the *JR 5.2.0*

Comment: You can post solution as an answer - to help others

Comment: the version of report the you use, needs to be the same version of the JAR, my iReport is 5.2.0 so my jar needs to be jasperreports-5.2.0.jar, another thing that you want it's the last version of the groovy-all, i think it's the 1.8.0

Comment: Just letting you know that you posted the solution as a comment. What Alex was saying is that you should post an answer to your own question (form at the bottom) and then accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Let me explain: if you're compiling your jasper report files (jrxml) with iReport-5.6.0 then you have to use jasperreports-5.6.0.jar at runtime..

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this by :

1. removing `language="groovy"`
2. (or) replacing `language="groovy"` with `language="java"` in my `JRXML` file

Don't forget to save and compile.

Answer (score 1):

It usually happens when your ireport and jasper jar version is different. In such case  compile the jrxml with java or your version of jar should be similar to ireport

```
String dir = request.getRealPath("/");
        
        try {
            JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(dir+ "/WEB-INF/jasper/SummaryReportExport.jrxml", dir+ "/WEB-INF/jasper/SummaryReportExport.jasper");
       } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ERROR;
        }
```