# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/compilers/GroovyEvaluator

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am getting the following problem while generating *JasperReports*'s report.

I am using *JasperReports 4.5.1* version, Java 1.8.

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/compilers/GroovyEvaluator
```

Could you please help anyone.

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062314/groovyevaluator-not-found ?

Comment: @Eeranna You can check this answer: [How to use subreport in jasper?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33792035/876298) if you don't use Groovy at report